# Add/remove items from windows 10 file explorer navigation pane

Tags: windows-10

How can I Add/remove items from windows 10 file explorer navigation pane ?

Note that I am not talking about 'quick access' sub items but the navigation pane itself

For example I want to remove onedrive and add c:\

Thx!

Comment: Ramhound, your answer there (and the reason why I removed my question) is that I don't want to add to the 'quick acces' but to the navigation pane itself.

Answer (score -2):

You can add things to the 'Favourites' tab by navigation to the directory you want, then right clicking 'Favourites' and then clicking 'Add current location to favourites'

Might not be what you wanted but thats also a very good way to get around if you need access an obscure folder quickly

Comment: thx but that is not what I want

Comment: Try editing the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\DelegateFolders\{F5FB2C77-0E2F-4A16-A381-3E560C68BC83}

Comment: thx Ben, that place has one entry 'Removable Drives'