# How do I add Custom Entries to the Windows 10 Navigation Pane?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, regedit, windows-10-quick-access

My goal is to add an entry to Windows 10's Navigation Pane that holds user-defined items. The idea is to create a new category outside of the existing ones so that items can be added under it without creating too many entries under Quick Access. Simply using "Pin to Quick Access" is unsatisfactory and all the searching I've done about this topic yields results that only relate to right clicking and pinning/unpinning folders.

I see that applications like OneDrive and Visual Studio are able to create their own dedicated entries. The highlighted category for Visual Studio in the screenshot is the closest representation to what I want to make. (Interestingly, the Visual Studio one only appears in file browser dialogs launched from Visual Studio. I would like my category to appear everywhere in the shell where the pane is present.)

[Windows 10 Navigation Pane showing existing categories and illustrating application specific custom entries that I am trying to implement.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuxxR.png)

What registry keys enable them to do this and is it possible for me to add a custom entry?

Comment: You can create custom libraries that point to one or more folders. It'll be a bit lower than the Quick Access location, but its easy to setup. Any custom items will be registry hacks and is very hard to do. It can work as long as the folders are local

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1231913/add-remove-items-from-windows-10-file-explorer-navigation-pane , which has a Registry location. Also see WinAero Tweker, https://winaero.com/add-custom-folders-or-control-panel-applets-to-navigation-pane-in-file-explorer/